# I tried to add SAP webservice link to my service reference and alot of error appear

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So I already added the service reference and straight away I got this errors.
I haven't even started programming yet.

[image: error]

https://ibb.co/kBhp2pZ

I haven't even started coding yet and try to build the solution but It's giving me error in the script called Reference.cs.

I tried resolving the error but to no avail

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Drawing;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.Windows.Forms;

            namespace test_web_SAP
            {
                public partial class Form1 : Form
                {
                    public Form1()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

I've also included the auto generated code from my visual studio

```
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // <auto-generated>
        //     This code was generated by a tool.
        //     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
        //
        //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
        //     the code is regenerated.
        // </auto-generated>
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        namespace test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE {


            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
            [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", ConfigurationName="SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK")]
            public interface ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK {

                // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the operation ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK is neither RPC nor document wrapped.
                [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions:ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK:ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKReq" +
                    "uest", ReplyAction="*")]
                [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
                test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1 ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK(test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest request);

                [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions:ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK:ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKReq" +
                    "uest", ReplyAction="*")]
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task<test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1> ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKAsync(test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest request);
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3752.0")]
            [System.SerializableAttribute()]
            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
            [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions")]
            public partial class ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

                private string bATCHField;

                private string mATERIALField;

                private string pLANTField;

                private string sPEC_STOCKField;

                private string sTOCK_CATField;

                private string sTORAGE_BINField;

                private string sTORAGE_LOCField;

                private string sTORAGE_TYPEField;

                private string wAREHOUSE_NOField;

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
                public string BATCH {
                    get {
                        return this.bATCHField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.bATCHField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("BATCH");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
                public string MATERIAL {
                    get {
                        return this.mATERIALField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.mATERIALField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("MATERIAL");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
                public string PLANT {
                    get {
                        return this.pLANTField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.pLANTField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("PLANT");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
                public string SPEC_STOCK {
                    get {
                        return this.sPEC_STOCKField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sPEC_STOCKField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("SPEC_STOCK");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
                public string STOCK_CAT {
                    get {
                        return this.sTOCK_CATField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sTOCK_CATField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("STOCK_CAT");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=5)]
                public string STORAGE_BIN {
                    get {
                        return this.sTORAGE_BINField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sTORAGE_BINField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("STORAGE_BIN");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=6)]
                public string STORAGE_LOC {
                    get {
                        return this.sTORAGE_LOCField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sTORAGE_LOCField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("STORAGE_LOC");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=7)]
                public string STORAGE_TYPE {
                    get {
                        return this.sTORAGE_TYPEField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sTORAGE_TYPEField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("STORAGE_TYPE");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=8)]
                public string WAREHOUSE_NO {
                    get {
                        return this.wAREHOUSE_NOField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.wAREHOUSE_NOField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("WAREHOUSE_NO");
                    }
                }

                public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
                    System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
                    if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                        propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3752.0")]
            [System.SerializableAttribute()]
            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
            [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions")]
            public partial class ZWM_MY_I_FM_BARCODE_MS : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

                private string tYPEField;

                private string mESSAGEField;

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
                public string TYPE {
                    get {
                        return this.tYPEField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.tYPEField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("TYPE");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
                public string MESSAGE {
                    get {
                        return this.mESSAGEField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.mESSAGEField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("MESSAGE");
                    }
                }

                public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
                    System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
                    if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                        propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3752.0")]
            [System.SerializableAttribute()]
            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
            [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions")]
            public partial class ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK_S : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

                private string mATERIALField;

                private string sTGE_LOCField;

                private string sTGE_TYPEField;

                private string sTGE_BINField;

                private decimal qUANTITYField;

                private string uOMField;

                private string bATCHField;

                private string sTOCK_CATField;

                private string sPEC_STOCKField;

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
                public string MATERIAL {
                    get {
                        return this.mATERIALField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.mATERIALField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("MATERIAL");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
                public string STGE_LOC {
                    get {
                        return this.sTGE_LOCField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sTGE_LOCField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("STGE_LOC");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
                public string STGE_TYPE {
                    get {
                        return this.sTGE_TYPEField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sTGE_TYPEField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("STGE_TYPE");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=3)]
                public string STGE_BIN {
                    get {
                        return this.sTGE_BINField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sTGE_BINField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("STGE_BIN");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
                public decimal QUANTITY {
                    get {
                        return this.qUANTITYField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.qUANTITYField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("QUANTITY");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=5)]
                public string UOM {
                    get {
                        return this.uOMField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.uOMField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("UOM");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=6)]
                public string BATCH {
                    get {
                        return this.bATCHField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.bATCHField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("BATCH");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=7)]
                public string STOCK_CAT {
                    get {
                        return this.sTOCK_CATField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sTOCK_CATField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("STOCK_CAT");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=8)]
                public string SPEC_STOCK {
                    get {
                        return this.sPEC_STOCKField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.sPEC_STOCKField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("SPEC_STOCK");
                    }
                }

                public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
                    System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
                    if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                        propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <remarks/>
            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3752.0")]
            [System.SerializableAttribute()]
            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
            [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions")]
            public partial class ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

                private ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK_S[] iTEMField;

                private ZWM_MY_I_FM_BARCODE_MS mSGField;

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK_S[] ITEM {
                    get {
                        return this.iTEMField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.iTEMField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("ITEM");
                    }
                }

                /// <remarks/>
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
                public ZWM_MY_I_FM_BARCODE_MS MSG {
                    get {
                        return this.mSGField;
                    }
                    set {
                        this.mSGField = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("MSG");
                    }
                }

                public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

                protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
                    System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
                    if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                        propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
                }
            }

            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
            [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
            [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
            public partial class ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest {

                [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", Order=0)]
                public test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK;

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest() {
                }

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest(test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK) {
                    this.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK = ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK;
                }
            }

            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
            [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
            [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
            public partial class ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1 {

                [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", Order=0)]
                public test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse;

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1() {
                }

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1(test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse) {
                    this.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse = ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse;
                }
            }

            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
            public interface ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKChannel : test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
            }

            [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
            [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
            public partial class ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK>, test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK {

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKClient() {
                }

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                        base(endpointConfigurationName) {
                }

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                        base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
                }

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                        base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
                }

                public ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                        base(binding, remoteAddress) {
                }

                [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
                test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1 test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK(test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest request) {
                    return base.Channel.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK(request);
                }

                public test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK(test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK1) {
                    test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest inValue = new test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest();
                    inValue.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK = ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK1;
                    test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1 retVal = ((test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK)(this)).ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK(inValue);
                    return retVal.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse;
                }

                [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task<test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1> test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKAsync(test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest request) {
                    return base.Channel.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKAsync(request);
                }

                public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKResponse1> ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKAsync(test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK) {
                    test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest inValue = new test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKRequest();
                    inValue.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK = ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK;
                    return ((test_web_SAP.SAP_WEB_SERVICE.ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCK)(this)).ZWM_MY_I_BARC_STOCKAsync(inValue);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: which service reference you added ?? give full name

Comment: I named my service reference as SAP_WEB_SERVICE is that wrong ?